# Where is Omni Channel Presence Status busy stored in schema

Tags: service-cloud-console, omnichannel, service

Anyone know where the "busy" flag that is checked when creating a new Omni-Channel presence status is stored? There is no field in ServicePresenceStatus. There is an IsAway flag in UserServicePresence but that is specific to each status instance of a user. I'm looking for a way to find via SOQL all statuses that are defined as "busy"?